# Find current element of slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am building a website with pages that are displayed as a slider. Each page has a unique ID, but all have a class named 'section'. Now what I cant seem to do is, finding the ID of the div which is being displayed on screen, the ID of "CURRENT PAGE" (see the image attached). The next/right button would horizontally scroll the website to the right and prev/left button would scroll website to the left.

Website/screen layout:
[image: Website/screen layout]

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rSuc6/)

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SxBZx/2/)

Fiddle one has next/prev button inside every div but I want to control the motion of the divs with one set of next and prev buttons.

This is the Javascript I'm using for the Prev/next buttons:

```
$('.next').stop().click(function () {

    if($(this).closest('.checkout').next().css('display') == 'none'){ 
        alert('a');
    }else{
        $(this).parent().animate({
            marginLeft: '-100%'
        }, 500);
        $(this).parent().next().animate({
            marginLeft: '0%'
        }, 500);
        $(this).parent().animate({
            marginLeft: '-100%'
        }, 500);
    }

});

$('.prev').click(function () {

    $(this).stop().parent().animate({
        marginLeft: '0%'
    },  500);
    $(this).stop().parent().prev().animate({
        marginLeft: '0%'
    },  500);

    $(this).stop().parent().animate({
        marginLeft: '0%'
    },  500);

});
```

Comment: Maybe you could add an empty class to the active screen. And use that to find the next and previous screens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**

How about looping over your `checkout` divs and checking which is the first one to have `margin-left: 0px;` ?

```
function getCurrentPage(){
   var current = "";
   $.each($(".checkout"), function(){
      if($(this).css("margin-left") == "0px"){
          current = this.id;
          return false;
      }
   });
   return current;
}
```

Fiddle 1: http://jsfiddle.net/rSuc6/3/

Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/SxBZx/3/

**Method 2**

Working further on Barthosz's answer, you can also use a global variable to keep track of your page:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SxBZx/5/

**Method 3**

You can also work with an `active` class.

On each next / prev click:

```
//remove current active
$(".active").removeClass("active");
//set new current to active
$(this).addClass("active");
//retrieve ID of active
$(".active").attr("id");
```

Comment: Thanks for that, now I need to do this with only one set of next/prev button. Currently, each div is having next/prev in it. Did you visit my project link? You will get an idea from that. The next and prev buttons are at the bottom in the navigation, they cannot be included on every page, but only in the navigation so $(this).parent wont work in this.

Comment: Updated my answer with more methods. As for your buttons, simply create a single `#prev` and `#next` div, and position them absolutely over your container. Their positions should not be animated.

Comment: This is a responsive design, I would rather not position absolute the buttons, or else I am sure client will find device(s) that wont show the buttons correctly. :/

Comment: You can position them absolutely *and* responsive. Set your container to `position: relative;` and position your buttons for example `left: 50px;` and `right: 50px;`

Comment: You mean position:relative?

Comment: OK great thanks. Can I do the required via the currentPage variable? "Required" as in, change pages with a single next/prev buttons.

Comment: EPIC! Thank you so much, saved my life man! Been at it since few hours now :/ I am fairly new/naive at jQuery so couldn't figure out the issue, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way (for me):

add this to your html to see result:

```
<span id="whichid"></span>
```

add this in front of your js

```
var page=0;
```

inside your if statements add:

```
page=page+1;
$('#whichid').text(page);
```

for next page and:

```
page=page-1;
$('#whichid').text(page);
```

for previous page.

You can use :nthoftype or :child or some similar selector to get your page id.

Comment: Adding a global jQuery variable would work better than a hidden element.